# defining a init contructor method in subclass is called overriding of init method of super class or we are defining a new init method to replace

Tags: python, overriding

```
class A:

    a = 10

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, n, r):
        self.name = n
        self.roll = r
```

I know practically it won't make a difference but I just wanted to know whether this will be constructor overriding or not because different parameters are used here so as per my knowledge it is not overriding but some people on the internet refer to it as overriding. Replacement should be the correct word according to me?. Please tell me if I am correct

Comment: Yes, you're overriding the superclass's constructor.

Comment: but overriding generally means same number of arguments. here we have an additional argument r.